# Maxima CAS: How to force log() into a product?

Tags: logarithms, products, computer-algebra-systems, maxima-software

Is there a simplification way to turn log of a product into a sum of logs in [Maxima CAS](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/)? I tried `radcan()`, but it does not change the expression. See the toy example: [TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##y02syMxN/P8/zSonP12joCg/pTS5RCO1okAjIjozVje3VFMnU8dQJ09T05qroCgzr0QjDc4qSkxJTswDCmha//8PAA)

```
f:log(product(exp(X[i]-mu),i,1,n));
print(f);
print(radcan(f));
```

both prints return:

```
      n
    /===\   X  - mu
     ! !     i
log( ! !  %e       ) 
     ! !
    i = 1
      n
    /===\   X  - mu
     ! !     i
log( ! !  %e       ) 
     ! !
    i = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found [`logexpand` variable](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_51.html), which is opposite to `logcontract`:

```
logexpand:all;
f:log(product(exp(X[i]-mu),i,1,n));
print(f);
print(radcan(f));
```

produces:

```
 n
====
\
 >    (X  - mu) 
/       i
====
i = 1
 n
====
\
 >    (X  - mu) 
/       i
====
i = 1
```